# Tracking segfault with valgrind, and understanding valgrind output

Tags: c++, valgrind

I am trying to debug my C++ program, which is segfaulting.

- I checked my code to see if I could find the cause of the segfault. I placed some `cout` statements to narrow down the location at which the fault occured.
- I found the function call which produces the segfault. It is inside a callback function. The line is

  `inputbox->TestFunc();`

although this is meaningless to the reader.

- This was confirmed by the backtrace in GDB. (I couldn't get any more useful info from GDB other than the backtrace, but I am not too familiar with debugging tools.)
- I attempted to produce a MWE, and failed. I failed because when I stripped down parts of the code to produce a MWE, the problem went away. (So my guess is it is something subtle, not trivial.)
- I tried writing a MWE from scratch, copying my inheritance structures, and this failed.
- Part of my problem is that I cannot simply remove "xyz" bit of code, because this changing one function argument breaks lots of other code due to inheritance structures that are in place.

I have done a few other tests, such as moving the "problem section of code" to different functions, such as the layer just below `int main()`, and in these places, there does not seem to be a problem.

A call to `inputbox->TestFunc2()` does not crash. `TestFunc2()` is not an overridden virtual function. `TestFunc()` is, and I think this might hint at the cause of the problem. (Although not directly, as copying the inhertance structure into a MWE makes the problem go away.)

Both of those test functions just cout the name of the function and then return. They don't read/write anything to memory.

- I didn't post anything to SO for a while because I wasn't able to formulate a question in a manner which might be able to get some meaningful response, however some internet searches suggested that I try to use valgrind to debug the issue.

With that, here is the valgrind output

```
==8379== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8379== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8379== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8379== Command: ./a.out
==8379== 
==8379== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8379==    at 0x4C32EA6: rawmemchr (vg_replace_strmem.c:1402)
==8379==    by 0x5E8C3C1: _IO_str_init_static_internal (strops.c:41)
==8379==    by 0x5E7FB96: vsscanf (iovsscanf.c:40)
==8379==    by 0x5E7A306: sscanf (sscanf.c:32)
==8379==    by 0xEC17E4A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==8379==    by 0xEC18182: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==8379==    by 0xEC1BBF8: drmGetDevice (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==8379==    by 0xD7622D6: ??? (in /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==8379==    by 0xD761694: ??? (in /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==8379==    by 0xD735988: ??? (in /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==8379==    by 0xD731B9A: ??? (in /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==8379==    by 0xD731FD1: glXQueryExtensionsString (in /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==8379== 
==8379== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==8379==    at 0x5EF6E70: __writev_nocancel (syscall-template.S:84)
==8379==    by 0x94BB41C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==8379==    by 0x94BB81C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==8379==    by 0x94BB89C: xcb_writev (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==8379==    by 0x6D6EA7D: _XSend (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==8379==    by 0x6D6EF71: _XReply (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==8379==    by 0x6D59E2E: XInternAtom (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==8379==    by 0x4EFE46A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x4EFF364: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x4EEF2EF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x4EEF07E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x4E55456: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==  Address 0xd1a9813 is 35 bytes inside a block of size 16,384 alloc'd
==8379==    at 0x4C2DBC5: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==8379==    by 0x6D5EEC5: XOpenDisplay (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==8379==    by 0x4EFD53F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x4EEF02B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x4E55456: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x10CF85: main (main.cpp:61)
==8379== 
_ftm_ address: 0x12a0b610
SetPosition(0, 0)
Inputbox::TestFunc2()
Inputbox::TestFunc()
Inputbox::Draw()

0,0
SetPosition(0, 600)
refreshdelay set to: 16
ENTERED MAIN
SetPosition(0, 0)
Inputbox::TestFunc2()
Inputbox::TestFunc()
Inputbox::Draw()
derived2::function()
function was called ok
Window address: 0xffefffa00
Window 0
Window::TestFunc()
this=0xffefffa00
FontTextureManager::TestFunc()
this=0x12a0b610
current_window->_ftm_ address: 0x12a0b610
==8379== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8379==    at 0x4EEBA2D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x128278: Window::Height() const (Window.hpp:773)
==8379==    by 0x12794E: fc_open(Window*) (FunctionCallback.cpp:133)
==8379==    by 0x10D257: main (main.cpp:109)
==8379== 
==8379== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==8379==    at 0x4EEBA32: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x128278: Window::Height() const (Window.hpp:773)
==8379==    by 0x12794E: fc_open(Window*) (FunctionCallback.cpp:133)
==8379==    by 0x10D257: main (main.cpp:109)
==8379== 
==8379== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==8379==    at 0x12827D: Window::Height() const (Window.hpp:774)
==8379==    by 0x12794E: fc_open(Window*) (FunctionCallback.cpp:133)
==8379==    by 0x10D257: main (main.cpp:109)
==8379== 
==8379== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8379==    at 0x4EEBA23: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x12823C: Window::Width() const (Window.hpp:766)
==8379==    by 0x127966: fc_open(Window*) (FunctionCallback.cpp:133)
==8379==    by 0x10D257: main (main.cpp:109)
==8379== 
==8379== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==8379==    at 0x4EEBA28: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==8379==    by 0x12823C: Window::Width() const (Window.hpp:766)
==8379==    by 0x127966: fc_open(Window*) (FunctionCallback.cpp:133)
==8379==    by 0x10D257: main (main.cpp:109)
==8379== 
==8379== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==8379==    at 0x128241: Window::Width() const (Window.hpp:767)
==8379==    by 0x127966: fc_open(Window*) (FunctionCallback.cpp:133)
==8379==    by 0x10D257: main (main.cpp:109)
==8379== 
SetPosition(400, 300)
INPUTBOX...
Inputbox::TestFunc2()
==8379== Invalid read of size 8
==8379==    at 0x1279BF: fc_open(Window*) (FunctionCallback.cpp:136)
==8379==    by 0x10D257: main (main.cpp:109)
==8379==  Address 0x340 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8379== 
==8379== 
==8379== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8379==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x340
==8379==    at 0x1279BF: fc_open(Window*) (FunctionCallback.cpp:136)
==8379==    by 0x10D257: main (main.cpp:109)
==8379==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==8379==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==8379==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==8379==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==8379==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==8379== 
==8379== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8379==     in use at exit: 29,970,438 bytes in 46,548 blocks
==8379==   total heap usage: 109,878 allocs, 63,330 frees, 61,448,020 bytes allocated
==8379== 
==8379== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8379==    definitely lost: 461,536 bytes in 124 blocks
==8379==    indirectly lost: 176 bytes in 4 blocks
==8379==      possibly lost: 28,306,879 bytes in 43,538 blocks
==8379==    still reachable: 1,201,847 bytes in 2,882 blocks
==8379==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8379== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==8379== 
==8379== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8379== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==8379== ERROR SUMMARY: 23 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

The key line appears to be `Invalid read of size 8` `at 0x1279BF: fc_open(Window*) (FunctionCallback.cpp:136)`

What does this information mean, and what should I be looking for in my code that might have caused this error?

Code snippet:

```
void fc_open(Window *const current_window)
{

    derived2 *object = new derived2;
    object->function();
    std::cout << "function was called ok" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Window address: " << current_window << std::endl;
    std::cout << current_window->TestName() << std::endl;
    current_window->TestFunc();
    current_window->_ftm_->TestFunc();
    std::cout << "current_window->_ftm_ address: " << current_window->_ftm_ << std::endl;
    Inputbox *inputbox = new Inputbox(current_window->_ftm_);
    std::cout << "inputbox=" << inputbox << std::endl;
    inputbox->SetPosition(current_window->Width() / 2, current_window->Height() / 2);
    std::cout << "INPUTBOX..." << std::endl;
    inputbox->TestFunc2();
    inputbox->TestFunc(); // BOOM

}
```

Comment: It means you read an invalid 64-bit value (probably a pointer if you're on a 64-bit system) in the `fc_open` function on line 136 in the source file `functionCallback.cpp`. For the most part, the message should be pretty clear, especially if you look at the code mentioned in the message.

Comment: Invalid read may be for example trying to dereference `delete`d memory. Or unowned memory on line 136 of `functionCallback.cpp`

Comment: Is there any reason why that would cause a crash in the context of a function call in a class which inherits from another class. ie; why an overridden function call causes a crash, but a function call to a regular member (not overridden) does not cause a crash?

Comment: Most probably you passed a NULL `Window *` to`fc_open` - that 0x340 address is extremely small, so it's likely to be an attempt to access a field in a big `struct` when the struct pointer is zero. BTW, you have numerous instances of conditionals over uninitialized values, which may or may not be related to the crash, but are clearly indicators of something wrong - for example, you may not be initializing variables that you are later reading.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I checked for that by printing the address of `Window*`, which was `Window address: 0xffefffa00`. This matches up with an earlier print statement in the `Window` constructor which prints the `this` pointer.

Comment: @user3728501 When using virtual dispatch the program likely has to look up the function to call in object's vtable through the pointer.  When not using virtual dispatch it can just call the function directly, so it may or may not have to read anything from memory pointed to.  Either way, the behavior is undefined and anything could happen.

Comment: Hmm that address looks a bit dodgy to me as well... What platform is this code running on? Is it 32 or 64 bit code?

Comment: BTW, did you try to print the value of `inputbox`? It's more likely that *it* is the null value...

Comment: Ok I will try that, however before the line which causes the crash, I call 2 other functions of `inputbox`, and neither of them caused a crash. I will add the code snippet so that you can see.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The address for inputbox is not null. It has a similar value to some of the other allocated objects which indicates that the allocation was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved: Information for future readers.

It is highly unlikely that this information will help anyone in future, but just in case, here is the cause of the problem.

First, let us review the code in the function which was causing the segfault:

```
Inputbox *inputbox = new Inputbox(current_window->_ftm_);
inputbox->SetPosition(current_window->Width() / 2, current_window->Height() / 2);
inputbox->TestFunc2();
inputbox->TestFunc();
```

- I have no idea why TestFunc2() didn't blow up and TestFunc() did.
- The problem was actually being caused by the call to SetPosition, which takes 2 integers as arguments.

Now let us check the Width and Height functions:

```
int Width() const
{
    int *w;
    SDL_GetWindowSize(_window_.get(), w, nullptr);
    return *w;
}
```

This is clearly wrong and was caused by not paying attention. It should be:

```
int Width() const
{
    int w;
    SDL_GetWindowSize(_window_.get(), &w, nullptr);
    return w;
}
```

Valgrind hinted at the cause of the problem in the printed messages about the Width and Height functions.

- I still don't fully understand why the segfault occured when it did however. My guess is this is due to some sort of optimization re-ordering?

Comment: That's why generally when I have this kind of bug I stop caring much about the sources and just go debugging in assembly. See exactly what instruction blew up, trace back the faulting value to see exactly where it came from, not unlike reverse engineering the compiled code. [Once the optimizer ran over your code, it's no longer what you expect](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041111-00/?p=37333#comment-224523), and if you have undefined behavior around reasoning "at source level" to explain the segfault often isn't really useful.

Comment: Use of uninitialized pointer `int *w;` causes undefined behavior. Whatever happens after - is just random.

Comment: Yes, quite an obvious mistake.